# The sum of the first natural 100 numbers

Tags: vb.net

new to coding,
Quick Homework problem Im having trouble on.
I must find the sum of the first 100 natural numbers. 1+2+3+4, and so on. While using "while loops".

This is what I have so far.

```
    Dim sum, count As Integer
    Const num As Integer = 1

    Console.WriteLine("The Sum of the first 100 natural numbers is:") 

 

    count = num + 1

    While count <= 100 
        Count = num + count
        
    End While
        Sum = count

    Console.WriteLine("{0}", sum) 
    Console.ReadLine()
```

I know for a fact the math and while loop is incorrect, but Im not sure how to fix it. I keep getting 101 as my answer.

Comment: what is wrong with adding print statements to see what happens, lower the loop test to `10` to limit the text dump, That is called **Debugging**

Comment: Enumerable.Range(1,100).Sum()

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the num constant and the line: count = num + 1

```
 While count <= 100
    sum += count
    count += 1
 End While
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Would changing the 100 to 200 and adding a division equation make it so itll add all of the first 100 even number together?

Answer (score 0):

I know you are learning and the solution must use a While loop but for fun see what you can do in 2 lines of code.

```
    Dim arrNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray
    Console.WriteLine(arrNumbers.Sum)
```

Comment: Thanks, makes me wonder why my I wasn't taught this instead Lol.

Comment: Because they are trying to teach you to think about how to program. Anyone can use a library, but knowing how to code is much more important.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question title asked for sums of all [1 - 100] as well as the evens and odds, here is some LINQ for each one

```
Dim sum = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Sum()
Dim sumEvens = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Sum(Function(i) If(i Mod 2 = 0, i, 0))
Dim sumOdds = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Sum(Function(i) If(i Mod 2 = 0, 0, i))
```

```
Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}, Sum evens: {sumEvens}, Sum odds: {sumOdds}")
```

> Sum: 5050, Sum evens: 2550, Sum odds: 2500

`Enumerable.Range(1, 100)` creates your sequence of all [1 - 100]. Call the LINQ function `Sum` to simply get the sum, or you can pass a lambda function to `Sum` to transform the numbers. Use `Mod` to select evens or odds. The method above sets odds to 0 for the evens, and vice-versa for the odds.

An alternative to this method of transforming the sequence is to use `Where` to select only even numbers then `Sum`, which may be more readable.

```
Dim sumEvens = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Where(Function(i) i Mod 2 = 0).Sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code you've done a few things in a weird way.

Let's simplify the code and see what's going wrong.

To start with you are setting `num` as a constant to the value of `1`. Since it's not changing, we'll put the value in directly.

You'd then have this:

```
count = 1 + 1

While count <= 100
    count = 1 + count
End While

sum = count
```

So that means `count` will start at `2` and goes up by one ***until the value of `count` is greater than `100`*** - and that's when it is `101`.

Then you set `sum` to `count` and you get `101`.

What you needed to do was start `count` as `1` and sum up the values inside the loop.

```
count = 1

While count <= 100
    sum = sum + count
    count = count + 1
End While
```

And that gives the correct result of `5050`.